# Outlook: Send test e-mail message: The server responded: 421 Cannot establish SSL

Tags: microsoft-outlook, user-accounts, pop3

I create account in Outlook.
Account Type: POP3

When I run test account settings, log in onto incoming mail server POP3 successfully.
But for send test e-mail message i get error:

*Send test e-mail message:   The server responded: 421 Cannot establish SSL*

What is solution for this problem.

Comment: Disable SSL in the send-side configuration of the account. Or, better, change the port to the correct SMTPS port (secure submission) for the server.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to make sure the mail server supports SSL for SMTP. And if it does, you also need to know on which port. The default port in Outlook for SMTP is 25, but in Google for example SSL is supported on port 465. Also your mail server might support other security protocols for SMTP, like TLS. Again Google establishes TLS connection on port 587. So really, you need to go your mail provider support and obtain this information from them. You can't really guess what combination of protocols and ports they are using.

All these settings in Outlook can be changed at: File -> Info -> Account Settings -> Email tab -> Select email account -> Change -> More Settings -> Advanced tab

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to ask postmaster "How to configure account properly"? Why do you think we are wizards here? If server respond `Cannot establish SSL` you can't use SSL for sending mail and have to use plain SMTP, as **written in plain English**

Comment: Yikes!  It's nothing personal I'm sure.